# No output in PowerShell Plugin of Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins, write-host

I'm using the Jenkins Plugin (**not pipeline**) *Windows Powershell* for my scripts. Everything is fine, if the script is written directly into the Command-Window.
But for some more complex operations I'm using a .ps1-File located on my SCM, since all that code is too confusing for that tiny *Command-Window*. The script is triggered properly, but I don't get any output (Write-Host) of that file.

How I run the script:

```
cd MyScripts
if ($env.CONDITION -eq "condition") {
    powershell -File .\myScript.ps1 $env.HOST
}
```

Is there any clue I'm missing?